# How to take Children of a ListView in Code-Behind

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a ListView with some buttons(created in code-behind). I want to take all theese buttons and place them in a variable:

```
Button tg = (Button)sender;
ListView st = (ListView) tg.Parent;
var a = st.Children(this function doesn't work for ListView, but it's similar to what should resolve my problem) ;

foreach(Button btn in a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ListView` uses data virtualization to have a better performance. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization. So the buttons may not rendered when they are not in your viewport. This causes you can't get all buttons of your `ListView`.

But through some trick, we can disable `ListView`'s data virtualization. Note that doing this may causes your app react slow when you have a mount of items in your `ListView`.

**Suppose you want this way.**

**First**, you need to modify `ListView`'s `ItemsPanel` to `StackPanel`, according to doc, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization.

```
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

**Second**, you can get all buttons using a helper function, it returns a `List` of your controls finded.

```
public static List<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        list.Add((T)child);
                    }

                    List<T> childItems = FindVisualChildren<T>(child);
                    if (childItems != null && childItems.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in childItems)
                        {
                            list.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Third, you can use it this way.

```
        var listButtons = FindVisualChildren<Button>(listView);
        foreach (var btn in listButtons )
        {
            //to do
        }
```

**Done!!!**

Comment: Thanks! I will try this when I will be at home!